# I want an already rigged game character (Both Deform and Control) to be able to fall apart/be animated in pieces, and still be usable in unity

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, unity

I have rigged my character using a **deform armature that will be exported to unity**, as well as a **control rig, that I will use in Blender to animate the character**.

The deform armature bones have **copy transform constraints to link it to the control rig**, and the control rig has the IK for the arms, hands and feet.

Pictures (#1 & #2) show my working setup. Pink is Deform rig, with copy transforms, mutli-coloured is control rig with custom shapes.

[image]

[image]

That's all working well.

The hard part is I also want to **create some animations where the character falls apart** (They are robots with limbs that aren't connected to one another). IE: I want the upper arm to be able to disconnect from the lower arm (Both are in a linked bone chain, in both rigs, currently).

I know I **could technically just split all the bones in chains on my deform rig**, since they will still follow the control rig, and when I want to animate is falling apart, I  turn off the copy transforms influence and I do the animation on that rig, but I am **worried about losing the armature hierarchy for use in unity.**

I have tried to **duplicate the deform rig, separate those bones and add another set of copy transforms** to the original deform rig, so I would basically toggle between the control rig and new "broken" rig to animate. But this didn't work, I think because the original deform rig has the bones all connected.

The picture (#3), shows my attempt at this and how when i move the hips on "broken" rig, the whole spine bone chain follows, and when I try move the two arm pieces, mes doesn't move cause the deform rig is still one chain. (Pink is the deform rig, octahedral is the "broken" rig). You can see the two copy transforms there too.

[image]

Is there any better way for me to approach this? I'm still fairly new to rigging, so I might not know of a constraint or work flow. I know I could do a quick fix if it was just for an animation in unity, but this is for a game.

**Thank you so much!**

Comment: "But this didn't work, I think because the original deform rig has the bones all connected." As long as bones in deform rig have connected trait, this cannot be done in Blender.  Make unconnected and do a quick test in Unity to make sure that doesn't screw anything up.  It shouldn't screw anything in Blender except auto IK.